# Windows .NET process hang in GC

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, garbage-collection, locking

I have a strangely hang .NET x86 process. It's a Windows service for processing background jobs. It is using SQL Server via linq2sql, RabbitMQ, Kafka, Redis and some other technologies.

For some reason this process stops processing any jobs from time to time, and the only way to fix it is to restart it. It's a pretty rare thing but very annoying.

I have a memory dump of this process in such a strange state and a PerfView record.

In a memory dump I see ~600 managed and unmanaged threads. I discovered that a lot of threads in a process are locked on some Monitors inside a few libraries (inside linq2sql and NLog) and our own code.
The chain of locks ends on a lot of threads making linq2sql queries, this threads have stacktraces like this: https://prnt.sc/v60k71

It seems like these threads are trying to get this lock: https://prnt.sc/v60m2b

There is one thread that accomplished this task: https://prnt.sc/v5bz4z

This thread is also in some kind of a lock or wait. On the next screenshot we can see that it is trying to allocate some memory and is waiting for GC to end: https://prnt.sc/v60os0

The main problem with this thread is that it is in such a state for **like a day!** I can say so because I discovered some objects in a stack of this thread which contains a DateTime.Now of a moment these objects are created, and this time is like a day before this memory dump was created. As I can say, all other threads are also locked for a day long. Maybe they become unlocked for very small periods, but it seems very unlikely.

I tried to investigate GC work. We use Server GC, the machine has 24 cores, so we have 24 GC threads in this process. 23 of them have stacktrace like this: https://prnt.sc/v58910

Here is a PerfView trace for such a thread, so we can see that it's waiting in a Sleep like 60% of time and it seems like it spends other 40% of time not on some useful work: https://prnt.sc/v5c82p

As I can see, in https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/coreclr/src/gc/gc.cpp in `gc_heap::mark_steal` we have `sleep(1)`, so I'm pretty sure this is it.

One of GC threads has this stacktrace: https://prnt.sc/v5wwxi

Here we have a PerfView of this thread: https://prnt.sc/v608x9

So it seems like GC is working, but very ineffectively? Why? How to fix it or how not to let process to get into such a state?

.NET Framework version:

```
0:336> lmv m mscor*
Browse full module list
start    end        module name
72020000 7342e000   mscorlib_ni   (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: mscorlib.ni.dll
    Image path: C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\c7625296f6cee933f010d4fca91738db\mscorlib.ni.dll
    Image name: mscorlib.ni.dll
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Has CLR image header, track-debug-data flag not set
    Timestamp:        Thu Sep 12 22:32:19 2019 (5D7A9D43)
    CheckSum:         0141EB31
    ImageSize:        0140E000
    File version:     4.8.4042.0
    Product version:  4.0.30319.0
    File flags:       8 (Mask 3F) Private
    File OS:          4 Unknown Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    Information from resource tables:
        CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
        ProductName:      Microsoft® .NET Framework
        InternalName:     mscorlib.dll
        OriginalFilename: mscorlib.dll
        ProductVersion:   4.8.4042.0
        FileVersion:      4.8.4042.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
        PrivateBuild:     DDBLD481
        FileDescription:  Microsoft Common Language Runtime Class Library
        LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
        Comments:         Flavor=Retail
```

Here are GC heaps:

```
Number of GC Heaps: 24
------------------------------
Heap 0 (007028b0)
generation 0 starts at 0xdb3ffa3c
generation 1 starts at 0xdb3ffa30
generation 2 starts at 0x01441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
01440000  01441000  0243fc2c  0xffec2c(16772140)
77470000  77471000  7846ff88  0xffef88(16773000)
88810000  88811000  8980ffac  0xffefac(16773036)
8c810000  8c811000  8d80ffe8  0xffefe8(16773096)
bc010000  bc011000  bd00ff9c  0xffef9c(16773020)
f4010000  f4011000  f500ffc4  0xffefc4(16773060)
db010000  db011000  db3ffa48  0x3eea48(4123208)
Large object heap starts at 0x19441000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
19440000  19441000  19493a58  0x52a58(338520)
ce810000  ce811000  d6811010  0x8000010(134217744)
Heap Size:       Size: 0xe43af58 (239316824) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 1 (00708410)
generation 0 starts at 0xfb16f168
generation 1 starts at 0xfb16f15c
generation 2 starts at 0x02441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
02440000  02441000  0343ff9c  0xffef9c(16773020)
f3010000  f3011000  f400ffac  0xffefac(16773036)
91010000  91011000  9200ffdc  0xffefdc(16773084)
ad010000  ad011000  ae00ff74  0xffef74(16772980)
c6010000  c6011000  c700ff94  0xffef94(16773012)
f7010000  f7011000  f800ffc4  0xffefc4(16773060)
fb010000  fb011000  fb16f174  0x15e174(1433972)
Large object heap starts at 0x19c41000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
19c40000  19c41000  19c41010  0x10(16)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x6157f74 (102072180) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 2 (0070df70)
generation 0 starts at 0xeb00ffcc
generation 1 starts at 0xeb00ffc0
generation 2 starts at 0x03441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
03440000  03441000  044354a0  0xff44a0(16729248)
63cb0000  63cb1000  64cb0000  0xfff000(16773120)
81010000  81011000  8200ffec  0xffefec(16773100)
8a810000  8a811000  8b80fcc0  0xffecc0(16772288)
b6010000  b6011000  b700fd34  0xffed34(16772404)
9f010000  9f011000  a000ffec  0xffefec(16773100)
ea010000  ea011000  eb00ffd8  0xffefd8(16773080)
Large object heap starts at 0x1a441000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
1a440000  1a441000  1a876ed0  0x435ed0(4415184)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x7423d14 (121781524) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 3 (007142d8)
generation 0 starts at 0xd84d4740
generation 1 starts at 0xd84d4734
generation 2 starts at 0x04441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
04440000  04441000  0543ffa8  0xffefa8(16773032)
66cb0000  66cb1000  67caffec  0xffefec(16773100)
83810000  83811000  8480ffdc  0xffefdc(16773084)
9b010000  9b011000  9c00ffc0  0xffefc0(16773056)
b2010000  b2011000  b300ffdc  0xffefdc(16773084)
c9010000  c9011000  ca00ff68  0xffef68(16772968)
f9010000  f9011000  fa00ffe4  0xffefe4(16773092)
d8010000  d8011000  d84d474c  0x4c374c(4994892)
Large object heap starts at 0x1ac41000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
1ac40000  1ac41000  1ac65030  0x24030(147504)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x74e05d4 (122553812) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 4 (00719e38)
generation 0 starts at 0xeeb07994
generation 1 starts at 0xeeb07988
generation 2 starts at 0x05441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
05440000  05441000  0643fc98  0xffec98(16772248)
5d0c0000  5d0c1000  5e0bff20  0xffef20(16772896)
85810000  85811000  8680f3b4  0xffe3b4(16769972)
8b810000  8b811000  8c810000  0xfff000(16773120)
ba010000  ba011000  bb00fff0  0xffeff0(16773104)
a3010000  a3011000  a400fee4  0xffeee4(16772836)
ee010000  ee011000  eeb079a0  0xaf69a0(11495840)
Large object heap starts at 0x1b441000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
1b440000  1b441000  1b441010  0x10(16)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x6aef7f0 (112130032) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 5 (007239a0)
generation 0 starts at 0xe0befdc4
generation 1 starts at 0xe0befdb8
generation 2 starts at 0x06441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
06440000  06441000  0743fe4c  0xffee4c(16772684)
64cb0000  64cb1000  65caffdc  0xffefdc(16773084)
86810000  86811000  8780ff88  0xffef88(16773000)
a5010000  a5011000  a600fcf0  0xffecf0(16772336)
bf010000  bf011000  c000ff00  0xffef00(16772864)
e0010000  e0011000  e0c04940  0xbf3940(12532032)
Large object heap starts at 0x1bc41000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
1bc40000  1bc41000  1bc65030  0x24030(147504)
cc010000  cc011000  ce011018  0x2000018(33554456)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x7c12328 (130097960) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 6 (0072a508)
generation 0 starts at 0xda8386f4
generation 1 starts at 0xda8386e8
generation 2 starts at 0x07441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
07440000  07441000  0843f4d8  0xffe4d8(16770264)
f5010000  f5011000  f600ffcc  0xffefcc(16773068)
9a010000  9a011000  9b00ff34  0xffef34(16772916)
b9010000  b9011000  ba00fe20  0xffee20(16772640)
da010000  da011000  da838700  0x827700(8550144)
Large object heap starts at 0x1c441000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
1c440000  1c441000  1c48ff10  0x4ef10(323344)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x4871808 (75962376) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 7 (00730068)
generation 0 starts at 0xe6c4b564
generation 1 starts at 0xe6c4b558
generation 2 starts at 0x08441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
08440000  08441000  09438b64  0xff7b64(16743268)
ef010000  ef011000  f000fff4  0xffeff4(16773108)
82010000  82011000  8300ffd8  0xffefd8(16773080)
af010000  af011000  b000fff4  0xffeff4(16773108)
c7010000  c7011000  c800ff08  0xffef08(16772872)
e6010000  e6011000  e6c572a8  0xc462a8(12870312)
Large object heap starts at 0x1cc41000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
1cc40000  1cc41000  1cc41010  0x10(16)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x5c39ce4 (96705764) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 8 (00735bc8)
generation 0 starts at 0xf22a4fb0
generation 1 starts at 0xf22a4fa4
generation 2 starts at 0x09441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
09440000  09441000  0a43c36c  0xffb36c(16757612)
7b470000  7b471000  7c470000  0xfff000(16773120)
8f010000  8f011000  9000f0fc  0xffe0fc(16769276)
a4010000  a4011000  a500fff4  0xffeff4(16773108)
bb010000  bb011000  bc00e704  0xffd704(16766724)
d7010000  d7011000  d800dcd0  0xffccd0(16764112)
f2010000  f2011000  f22a4fbc  0x293fbc(2703292)
Large object heap starts at 0x1d441000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
1d440000  1d441000  1d441010  0x10(16)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x62857fc (103307260) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 9 (0073b728)
generation 0 starts at 0xe201100c
generation 1 starts at 0xe2011000
generation 2 starts at 0x0a441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
0a440000  0a441000  0b432154  0xff1154(16716116)
67cb0000  67cb1000  68c86368  0xfd5368(16601960)
92010000  92011000  9300fbd8  0xffebd8(16772056)
a9010000  a9011000  aa00ffa8  0xffefa8(16773032)
be010000  be011000  bf00fc18  0xffec18(16772120)
de010000  de011000  deddf1a4  0xdce1a4(14475684)
e2010000  e2011000  e2011018  0x18(24)
Large object heap starts at 0x1dc41000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
1dc40000  1dc41000  1dc41010  0x10(16)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x5d90e20 (98111008) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 10 (00741288)
generation 0 starts at 0xe59f9eb4
generation 1 starts at 0xe59f9ea8
generation 2 starts at 0x0b441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
0b440000  0b441000  0c43ff28  0xffef28(16772904)
7d470000  7d471000  7e46ffd0  0xffefd0(16773072)
93010000  93011000  9400ff48  0xffef48(16772936)
aa010000  aa011000  ab00fa8c  0xffea8c(16771724)
c3010000  c3011000  c400fcb4  0xffecb4(16772276)
e5010000  e5011000  e59f9ec0  0x9e8ec0(10391232)
Large object heap starts at 0x1e441000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
1e440000  1e441000  1e465030  0x24030(147504)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x5a07470 (94401648) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 11 (007475f0)
generation 0 starts at 0xdc01100c
generation 1 starts at 0xdc011000
generation 2 starts at 0x0c441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
0c440000  0c441000  0d437d90  0xff6d90(16739728)
78470000  78471000  7946ffe0  0xffefe0(16773088)
89810000  89811000  8a80ff74  0xffef74(16772980)
a8010000  a8011000  a900ff38  0xffef38(16772920)
c4010000  c4011000  c500d770  0xffc770(16762736)
dd010000  dd011000  dde6d38c  0xe5c38c(15057804)
dc010000  dc011000  dc03289c  0x2189c(137372)
Large object heap starts at 0x1ec41000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
1ec40000  1ec41000  1ec41010  0x10(16)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x5e6dfc4 (99016644) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 12 (0074d150)
generation 0 starts at 0xf05c5e00
generation 1 starts at 0xf05c5df4
generation 2 starts at 0x0d441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
0d440000  0d441000  0e434334  0xff3334(16724788)
65cb0000  65cb1000  66cad148  0xffc148(16761160)
96010000  96011000  9700ff14  0xffef14(16772884)
b4010000  b4011000  b500afcc  0xff9fcc(16752588)
a1010000  a1011000  a200df68  0xffcf68(16764776)
f0010000  f0011000  f05c5e0c  0x5b4e0c(5983756)
Large object heap starts at 0x1f441000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
1f440000  1f441000  1f441010  0x10(16)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x559a0e0 (89759968) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 13 (00754aa8)
generation 0 starts at 0xfc01100c
generation 1 starts at 0xfc011000
generation 2 starts at 0x0e441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
0e440000  0e441000  0f4369f0  0xff59f0(16734704)
fe010000  fe011000  ff00ffec  0xffefec(16773100)
8e010000  8e011000  8f00e6d4  0xffd6d4(16766676)
ac010000  ac011000  ad00fe00  0xffee00(16772608)
c1010000  c1011000  c200fc6c  0xffec6c(16772204)
e3010000  e3011000  e3c67088  0xc56088(12935304)
fc010000  fc011000  fc011018  0x18(24)
Large object heap starts at 0x1fc41000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
1fc40000  1fc41000  1fc41010  0x10(16)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x5c45bcc (96754636) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 14 (0075e800)
generation 0 starts at 0xe4c1ec74
generation 1 starts at 0xe4c1ec68
generation 2 starts at 0x0f441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
0f440000  0f441000  10437ef8  0xff6ef8(16740088)
5c0c0000  5c0c1000  5d0bffe8  0xffefe8(16773096)
84810000  84811000  8580ff9c  0xffef9c(16773020)
9c010000  9c011000  9d00ffec  0xffefec(16773100)
b8010000  b8011000  b900ee4c  0xffde4c(16768588)
9e010000  9e011000  9f00ff54  0xffef54(16772948)
e4010000  e4011000  e4c1ec80  0xc0dc80(12639360)
Large object heap starts at 0x20441000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
20440000  20441000  20441010  0x10(16)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x6bfe898 (113240216) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 15 (00764150)
generation 0 starts at 0xfd01100c
generation 1 starts at 0xfd011000
generation 2 starts at 0x10441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
10440000  10441000  1143fe74  0xffee74(16772724)
69cb0000  69cb1000  6acafe88  0xffee88(16772744)
94010000  94011000  9500fc30  0xffec30(16772144)
b0010000  b0011000  b100fc4c  0xffec4c(16772172)
c5010000  c5011000  c600f4c4  0xffe4c4(16770244)
e1010000  e1011000  e1ef4660  0xee3660(15611488)
fd010000  fd011000  fd011018  0x18(24)
Large object heap starts at 0x20c41000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
20c40000  20c41000  20c41010  0x10(16)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x5edd0c4 (99471556) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 16 (0076f1d8)
generation 0 starts at 0xf117d5d8
generation 1 starts at 0xf117d5cc
generation 2 starts at 0x11441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
11440000  11441000  1243fac8  0xffeac8(16771784)
68cb0000  68cb1000  69caffb0  0xffefb0(16773040)
98010000  98011000  9900fac0  0xffeac0(16771776)
b7010000  b7011000  b800ffbc  0xffefbc(16773052)
a2010000  a2011000  a300fa74  0xffea74(16771700)
f1010000  f1011000  f117d5e4  0x16c5e4(1492452)
Large object heap starts at 0x21441000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
21440000  21441000  21479050  0x38050(229456)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x519e59c (85583260) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 17 (0077aa98)
generation 0 starts at 0xfa01100c
generation 1 starts at 0xfa011000
generation 2 starts at 0x12441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
12440000  12441000  13438aac  0xff7aac(16743084)
58e00000  58e01000  59dffff0  0xffeff0(16773104)
87810000  87811000  8880fe90  0xffee90(16772752)
ab010000  ab011000  ac00ffd8  0xffefd8(16773080)
c0010000  c0011000  c100e214  0xffd214(16765460)
f6010000  f6011000  f6f98b74  0xf87b74(16284532)
fa010000  fa011000  fa011018  0x18(24)
Large object heap starts at 0x21c41000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
21c40000  21c41000  21c65030  0x24030(147504)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x5f9d6d4 (100259540) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 18 (0077dea8)
generation 0 starts at 0xe8848d64
generation 1 starts at 0xe8848d58
generation 2 starts at 0x13441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
13440000  13441000  144198cc  0xfd88cc(16615628)
7e470000  7e471000  7f46f07c  0xffe07c(16769148)
80010000  80011000  80fb0a68  0xf9fa68(16382568)
9d010000  9d011000  9e00fbac  0xffebac(16772012)
b5010000  b5011000  b600ffe8  0xffefe8(16773096)
a0010000  a0011000  a100d47c  0xffc47c(16761980)
e8010000  e8011000  e885928c  0x84828c(8684172)
Large object heap starts at 0x22441000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
22440000  22441000  22441010  0x10(16)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x67b865c (108758620) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 19 (0077c4a0)
generation 0 starts at 0xdfb2d62c
generation 1 starts at 0xdfb2d620
generation 2 starts at 0x14441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
14440000  14441000  154341c8  0xff31c8(16724424)
79470000  79471000  7a46ff3c  0xffef3c(16772924)
90010000  90011000  9100ffc4  0xffefc4(16773060)
a6010000  a6011000  a700ffec  0xffefec(16773100)
c2010000  c2011000  c300595c  0xff495c(16730460)
df010000  df011000  dfb33848  0xb22848(11675720)
Large object heap starts at 0x22c41000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
22c40000  22c41000  22c41010  0x10(16)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x5b07268 (95449704) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 20 (0077f8b0)
generation 0 starts at 0xeb85d3e0
generation 1 starts at 0xeb85d3d4
generation 2 starts at 0x15441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
15440000  15441000  1643fdf8  0xffedf8(16772600)
7c470000  7c471000  7d46ffc4  0xffefc4(16773060)
95010000  95011000  9600fedc  0xffeedc(16772828)
b1010000  b1011000  b200ffec  0xffefec(16773100)
ca010000  ca011000  cb00ff24  0xffef24(16772900)
eb010000  eb011000  eb85d3ec  0x84c3ec(8700908)
Large object heap starts at 0x23441000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
23440000  23441000  23441010  0x10(16)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x5846fa4 (92565412) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 21 (00779090)
generation 0 starts at 0xed72ecf8
generation 1 starts at 0xed72ecec
generation 2 starts at 0x16441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
16440000  16441000  17437418  0xff6418(16737304)
e9010000  e9011000  ea009284  0xff8284(16745092)
99010000  99011000  9a00fbf8  0xffebf8(16772088)
b3010000  b3011000  b400fb5c  0xffeb5c(16771932)
cb010000  cb011000  cc00fd68  0xffed68(16772456)
ed010000  ed011000  ed72ed04  0x71dd04(7462148)
Large object heap starts at 0x23c41000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
23c40000  23c41000  23c41010  0x10(16)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x570886c (91261036) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 22 (00774278)
generation 0 starts at 0xf801100c
generation 1 starts at 0xf8011000
generation 2 starts at 0x17441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
17440000  17441000  1842e658  0xfed658(16701016)
4f720000  4f721000  5071d2f8  0xffc2f8(16761592)
ec010000  ec011000  ed00ff40  0xffef40(16772928)
a7010000  a7011000  a800ff4c  0xffef4c(16772940)
bd010000  bd011000  be00fe18  0xffee18(16772632)
d9010000  d9011000  d9da7da0  0xd96da0(14249376)
f8010000  f8011000  f8011018  0x18(24)
Large object heap starts at 0x24441000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
24440000  24441000  24441010  0x10(16)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x5d7d3bc (98030524) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 23 (007812b8)
generation 0 starts at 0xe7670e10
generation 1 starts at 0xe7663454
generation 2 starts at 0x18441000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin  allocated      size
18440000  18441000  1943f7b0  0xffe7b0(16770992)
7a470000  7a471000  7b46de30  0xffce30(16764464)
97010000  97011000  9800fd74  0xffed74(16772468)
ae010000  ae011000  af00ff1c  0xffef1c(16772892)
c8010000  c8011000  c900ff28  0xffef28(16772904)
e7010000  e7011000  e7670e1c  0x65fe1c(6684188)
Large object heap starts at 0x24c41000
 segment     begin  allocated      size
24c40000  24c41000  24c41010  0x10(16)
Heap Size:       Size: 0x5657fc4 (90537924) bytes.
------------------------------
GC Heap Size:    Size: 0x986ab2d4 (2557129428) bytes.
```

Comment: This is a really long question with a lot of details. Try breaking it down to a shorter question with less details... Try being more precise and ask a general question, this question is really specific to your scenario. You can also add a bounty, maybe someone will do it for a bounty...